# возможно ли избавиться от try-catch?

Tags: java, spring, рефакторинг

подскажите, можно ли этот код, как то упростить, точнее не использовать try catch

```
Object tParameters = node.get("parameters");
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    ConnectionOne connectionOne = mapper.convertValue(tParameters, ConnectionOne.class);
    return new Server().setParameters(connectionOne);
}catch (Exception e){}
try {
    ConnectionTwo connectionTwo = mapper.convertValue(tParameters, ConnectionTwo.class);
    return new Server().setParameters(connectionTwo);
}catch (Exception e){}
```

---

```
public class Server<T> {
    private T parameters;

    public T getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public Server setParameters(T parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас второй блок зависим от первого, поэтому, развязать это можно через if условно, при условии, что есть ф-ция типа `tryconvertValue`. Ф-ции умеющее создавать условие могут иметь префиксы is- try- can-. Я с классом ObjectMapper не знаком, возможно есть вариант без исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но при этом вы должны будите его отловить и обработать выше по уровню вложенности.

```
void somemethod() { 
try{ .... } 
catch(..) 
{} 
}

void anotherOne() { somemeMethod();}
```

после изменения

```
void somemethod() throws Exception { 
 .... 
}

void anotherOne() { 
try {
 somemeMethod();
} catch (....) 
{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, Вы можете написать кастомный deserializer, который будет конвертить в тот или иной класс на основании какого-либо поля. В Jackson есть много возможностей настроить это с помощью аннотаций ([можно посмотреть здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)).